# How to include one css file into another with flask?

Tags: python, css, flask

Is there any way to include one css file into another css file in a python flask way like the

{% include 'path/to/html/file' %} instead of using css @import in other to avoid multiple http

request and have a neat code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the usual practice is to treat a CSS file as static, it's possible to instead treat it as a template. You'll do something like

1. Add a route to return CSS. This will look something like

```
from Flask import make_response, render_template

@app.route('/style.css')
def css():
    resp = make_response(render_template("style.css"))
    resp.headers['Content-type'] = 'text/css'
    return resp
```

2. Add a template named "style.css" to your template folder. Except that rather than being HTML, it will contain CSS. All of the power of Jinja2 is at your disposal here, including the `include` mechanism.
3. Reference this from HTML using

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('css') }}">
```

Answer (score 0):

Flask uses Jinja2, a template engine, to manage sub-templates with the `{% includes "<filename>" %}` tag, and it is unlikely to be easy to find something similar for css. I take it you want to reuse one css file across multiple pages, but still have a custom css file for each page.

Well, luckily in HTML, you can put as many stylesheet links as you like at the top of the page, using

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="path/to/filename">
```

Seeing as you're using flask, it might be a good idea to put your application-wide stylesheets in your base template, which is then inherited by other templates (`{% extends "<filename>" %}`), and then each template specific template can also have its own stylesheet links.

This should solve the problem.

Also, why can't you use css import? Your question was somewhat unclear.

Comment: Using css import statement requires additional server requests which can lead to slow performance.

Comment: Ah I see. If you want to minimise server load, unfortunately my answer can't help you there as it still makes a request to the server for that base css file. In fact, the only way to not make a request is some sort of css hierarchy engine that can do it at runtime in a specific folder like Jinja. Don't know of any but you could look into it.